# Bluetooth Control GUI using Winforms C# 32Feet library

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, bluetooth

I am currently developing a modular Winforms C# GUI for robotics control. Bluetooth will be the method of communication and thus I writing a bluetooth control gui which will be packaged as a custom toolbox.

My problem is that, the program does not execute anything after the line

```
BluetoothListener bluelistener = new BluetoothListener(uuid);
```

My entire code below is pasted below. Can anyone please assist me with this. Thank you in advance.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(rbClient.Checked)
        {
            connectAsClient();
        }
        else
        {
            connectAsServer();
        }
    }

    private void connectAsServer()
    {
        Thread bluetoothServerthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(serverConnectThread));
        bluetoothServerthread.Start();
    }

    Guid uuid = new Guid("e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974");

    public void serverConnectThread()
    {
        updateUI("Server Started, Waiting for client...");
        BluetoothListener bluelistener = new BluetoothListener(uuid);
        bluelistener.Start();
        BluetoothClient conn = bluelistener.AcceptBluetoothClient();

        updateUI("Client has connected...");
    }

    private void updateUI(string message)
    {
        Func<int> del = delegate () { tbOutput.AppendText(message + System.Environment.NewLine);
            return 0;
        };

        Invoke(del);
    }

    private void connectAsClient()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say it doesnt execute, do you get any errors?

Comment: Nope, it just outputs "Server Started, Waiting for client..." each time i click

Comment: if you put a break point on it and step through the code, where does this take you?

Comment: wihtout working on it directly I think part of the problem is that you have started your thread, but you're not actually working in your thread

Comment: In the spirit of stack overflow, what was the end solution?